# Electron extending with native C# code

Tags: c#, .net, electron

I have a .NET C# component i would to intergrate in  my electron project.I have used this library `edge.js` but build the app shows below error

```
Uncaught Exception:
Error: /var/www/edge-electron/node_modules/electron-edge/build/Release/edge_nativeclr.node: undefined symbol: _ZN2v816FunctionTemplate3NewEPNS_7IsolateEPFvRKNS_20FunctionCallbackInfoINS_5ValueEEEENS_5LocalIS4_EENSA_INS_9SignatureEEEi
    at Error (native)
    at process.module.(anonymous function) [as dlopen] (ELECTRON_ASAR.js:173:20)
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (module.js:583:18)
    at Object.module.(anonymous function) [as .node] (ELECTRON_ASAR.js:173:20)
    at Module.load (module.js:473:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:432:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:424:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:483:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/edge-electron/node_modules/electron-edge/lib/edge.js:49:8)
```

Below is sample code of electron boiler-plate with edge.js sample code

```
const electron = require('electron')
const edge = require('edge')
// Module to control application life.
const app = electron.app
// Module to create native browser window.
const BrowserWindow = electron.BrowserWindow

const path = require('path')
const url = require('url')

// Keep a global reference of the window object, if you don't, the window will
// be closed automatically when the JavaScript object is garbage collected.
let mainWindow

var helloWorld = edge.func(`
  async (input) => {
    return '.NET Welcomes ' + input.ToString()
  }
`)

function createWindow () {
  // Create the browser window.
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({width: 800, height: 600})

  // and load the index.html of the app.
  mainWindow.loadURL(url.format({
    pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'),
    protocol: 'file:',
    slashes: true
  }))

  // Open the DevTools.
  mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools()

  // Emitted when the window is closed.
  mainWindow.on('closed', function () {
    // Dereference the window object, usually you would store windows
    // in an array if your app supports multi windows, this is the time
    // when you should delete the corresponding element.
    mainWindow = null
  })

  // Edge functionality
  mainWindow.on('show', function () {
    // Dereference the window object, usually you would store windows
    console.log('shown')
    helloWorld('JavaScript', function (error, result) {
      if (error) throw error
      console.log(result)
    })
  })
}

// This method will be called when Electron has finished
// initialization and is ready to create browser windows.
// Some APIs can only be used after this event occurs.
app.on('ready', createWindow)

// Quit when all windows are closed.
app.on('window-all-closed', function () {
  // On OS X it is common for applications and their menu bar
  // to stay active until the user quits explicitly with Cmd + Q
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit()
  }
})

app.on('activate', function () {
  // On OS X it's common to re-create a window in the app when the
  // dock icon is clicked and there are no other windows open.
  if (mainWindow === null) {
    createWindow()
  }
})

// In this file you can include the rest of your app's specific main process
// code. You can also put them in separate files and require them here.
```

Any ideas on how i would go about this , any alternatives ? anything ?

Comment: Have you tried a Debug build? The question is what symbol is actually missing...

Comment: @Konstantin no , didnt know of that , but i figured problem was was on node rebuild

Comment: Then it's worth answering your own question with as much details as possible and then accepting it. It could help someone else, in the end.

Comment: @Konstantin yes will do , being very busy of late

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Just use [electron-edge](https://github.com/kexplo/electron-edge) and everything will work.